# PHP Codecompletion in HTML5 file

Tags: php, eclipse, html, code-completion

I've installed Eclipse Luna with PHP Extension from the eclipse website. Now I have some php files only and some html files which should contain php scripts. In PHP the code completion works well, but if I want to get a code completion in the HTML5 file where I'm adding the php script it won't work. How can I force code completion for PHP in HTML file as well?

Comment: Do you have the HTML files named with the .html extension? If so, sounds like code completion is not happening because the editor expects only plain HTML in those files, not php code. Just change the file extension of those files to .php if that is the case.

Comment: Yes the files are named with .html, because they are plain html files with some PHP scripts in the body section. I'm not sure if they are working if I rename them to .php

Comment: If php code is in the body, then they are PHP files. PHP files can contain plain html outside of the php opening and closing tags. Once you rename them with the .php extension, they will work, and code completion should also work.